# Eventbrite get user data using API code

Tags: eventbrite

I have download the Eventbrite API code for the PHP.
I have successfully made the connection with the Eventbrite using API code but i am not able to retrieve user data yet.

So kindly help me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have initialized the API client with your user's [authentication tokens](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication) in order to access private user data.

The [user_list_events() method](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/) should provide all of the event content from the authenticated user account.